# SQL Server table from an Excel spreadsheet without a unique column using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating a database from exported CRM data. Every export thus far has had either a unique column that could be used as a primary key or a combination of columns that I could use to create a composite primary key.

I have one data set that actually has duplicate rows that are legit and no column id or a unique way to identify each row.

The process I'm creating is fairly automated. I have a Sharepoint location in which the spreadsheets are placed and SSIS packages that pull the data from these sheets and load them into the database. I need a way to create a key for a row that can be reproduced to prevent more than the duplicate rows that are already there from being uploaded.

I've thought of maybe creating a calculated column that concatenates a number onto a composite key to show this is the first occurrence of this data and so on. So that if there are two occurrences, it would be Col1_Col2_Col3_1 and Col1_Col2_Col3_2 would be uploaded. Therefore if that sheet was not changed out in time on Sharepoint, then those two occurrences would not be uploaded.

Is it possible to count the occurrence of a row in the set and not just a total of occurrences of this row data? I am just really lost and need a solid place to start with this problem that seems almost impossible. I am open to any solution, whether it is a C# script in SSIS, or done on the server end, whatever I can do to come up with a solution that is reliable over time I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data as-is (with duplicates) into a working table in sql, and then use `row_number()`:

```sql
create table HasDuplicates(i int, j int, k int);

-- load in your data, I'll just do some inserts with one duplicate pair:
insert HasDuplicates(i, j, k) values (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)

-- generate "uniqueified" data. Since the "order by" is irrelevant, I'll just use a constant
select   i, j, k, instance = row_number() over (partition by i, j, k order by (select 1))
--into     Deduplicated <- uncomment this to save the result as a new table
from     HasDuplicates
```